# Is it necessary to compress short Websocket messages?

Tags: websocket, latency

I am working on a game project that uses Websocket for communication.  Back end is a Spring boot application.  Right now an example message would look like:

{"type":"EnemyHpChange","id":0,"value":-5}

As you can see, the message can easily be shorten to 2 bytes in binary, maybe use 6 bits for message type, 2 bits for id, etc.

Reducing latency is of interest to me since this is a game, but how much faster does it make to compress a message like this?

Comment: I am going to compress it anyways, but I still want to know what difference it makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. As far as theories go, network latency might not be effected while avoiding the JSON parser might have a desired effect as far as perceived latency.
2. Only tests can correctly observe performance changes. Theories are nice, but there are complex optimizations under the hood and they produce unforeseen effects.

#### Network latency

The reason behind the theory is the MTU for TCP/IP packets. It is likely that both messages fit within a single packet and so the network layer might behave the same.

On the other hand, if you have many messages, than you could fit more messages within the same packet, thus optimizing network traffic (which is still questionable, as this depends on the message frequency).

I'm not sure, but as far as I can recall, MTU values in the wild are often around the 500 bytes or less.

#### Parser latency

On the other hand, once the client gets the data, than binary data is often faster and easier to parse than JSON.

These are very short messages, but still, it is likely that memory consumption and speed of parsing will effect perceived latency as far as the client goes.

Note that perceived latency doesn't change the network delay, but the responsiveness of the client and the speed at which an event translates to a perceived change in state.